# How to remove a tag on a docker image without deleting any layers

Tags: docker

I can use `docker image rm --no-prune my:image` to keep *most* of the layers; but I have found that it removes the most last layer.

A simplified example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN echo "hello"
RUN echo "world"
```

Building it:

```sh
$ docker build --tag my:image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
89d9c30c1d48: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:c19173c5ada610a5989151111163d28a67368362762534d8a8121ce95cf2bd5a
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 965ea09ff2eb
Step 2/3 : RUN echo "hello"
 ---> Running in dff99f3e8991
hello
Removing intermediate container dff99f3e8991
 ---> bffa49d7d012
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "world"
 ---> Running in 20101e7149ba
world
Removing intermediate container 20101e7149ba
 ---> 9f6a7f60fd0d
Successfully built 9f6a7f60fd0d
Successfully tagged my:image
```

And then building it again:

```sh
$ docker build --tag my:image .                                                                                                                    [16:59:58]
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 965ea09ff2eb
Step 2/3 : RUN echo "hello"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bffa49d7d012
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "world"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9f6a7f60fd0d
Successfully built 9f6a7f60fd0d
Successfully tagged my:image
```

Note that the steps are cached. Now if I delete the image using `--no-prune`, the cli reports that it has deleted a SHA:

```sh
$ docker image rm --no-prune my:image
Untagged: my:image
Deleted: sha256:9f6a7f60fd0ddf06d079e9d1a5bd608a7dd85f6f00e7bacc79082a8ea4dc6601
```

Now when I rebuild the image, the last layer gets rebuilt:

```sh
$ docker build --tag my:image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 965ea09ff2eb
Step 2/3 : RUN echo "hello"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bffa49d7d012
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "world"
 ---> Running in f09302ce5295
world
Removing intermediate container f09302ce5295
 ---> 224a0d5007dd
Successfully built 224a0d5007dd
Successfully tagged my:image
```

How do I prevent docker from removing the last layer whilst removing tag from the image?

Answer (score 0):

So I gave up trying to find a good solution for this; and just went with the hacky version.

By tagging an image with another tag, removing the image doesn't remove any layers. Then moving that tag to another image still doesn't remove the image layers. So to leave all the layers in place you need to:

```
docker image tag my:image tmp
docker image rm my:image
```

Obviously this leaves the `tmp` image laying around, so we can remove it in a similar manner(where `alpine` is an image you're keeping):

```
docker image tag alpine tmp
docker image rm tmp
```

There is no need to use `--no-prune` for these as docker won't remove layers if there is another reference to them.